# How do I get the runtime Class of a parameterized Type in a Scala trait

Tags: scala

I'm trying to implement a Scala trait that handles the details of interfacing with a Java library that requires us to create

What I want to do is something like:

```
trait SomeTrait[A] extends JavaAPI {
  def foo = {
    callApi(classOf[A])
  }

  override def bar = {
    foo
  }
}
```

Note that bar is actually overriding a method from a base class, so I can't change it's signature.

I've tried several variations with Manifests, etc., but can't quite get this to work. Is there a way to get the runtime class of a parameterized type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This flavour should do the trick:

```
trait SomeTrait[A] {
  def foo(implicit ev: Manifest[A]) = {
    callApi(ev.erasure)
  }
}
```

**update** At some point, the manifest must be injected via a method parameter.  A constructor would be a good choice, if traits could have them.

Actually, they can!  The trait has the constructor of whatever it's mixed-in to, so if you specify an abstract manifest that deriving classes *must* define...

```
trait SomeTrait {
  def ev: Manifest[_] //abstract
  def foo = println(ev.erasure)
}

//this `ev` provides the implementation, note that it MUST be a val, or var
class Concrete[T](implicit val ev: Manifest[T]) extends SomeTrait
```

And all is good again.

Comment: This is close, but I need to call foo() from within the trait. When I try that with this approach, I get a compiler error: "could not find implicit value for parameter ev:Manifest[A]. I've updated my example to reflect the (more accurate) spec.

Comment: `ev.erasure` is deprecated. You should now use `ev.runtimeClass`.

Answer (score 5):

You have to get the manifest in there somehow, and traits have no constructor parameters.  Only you can say what tradeoff you want to make.  Here's another one.

```
trait SomeTrait[A] {
  implicit def manifesto: Manifest[A]

  def foo = println(manifest[A].erasure)
}
object SomeTrait {
  def apply[A: Manifest] : SomeTrait[A] = new SomeTrait[A] { def manifesto = manifest[A] }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Due to type erasure, the compiler has no way to figure out what the type should be **within the trait**. Thus what you want can't be done. However, you could make it a class. That way the compiler can pass an evidence parameter when an instance is created.

```
class SomeTrait[A](implicit ev: Manifest[A]) extends JavaApi {
  def foo = {
    callApi(ev.erasure)
  }


  override def bar = {
    foo
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little inconvenient to do so in your code, but you can do this

```
trait SomeTrait[A] extends JavaAPI {
  def objType: Class[A]
  def foo = {
    callApi(objType)
  }

  override def bar = {
    foo
  }
}

object SomeImplementation with SomeTrait[SomeObject] {
  val objType: Class[SomeObject] = classOf[SomeObject]
}
```

I know it is a little wordy, but that's the way I solved this problem. I hope to find a better solution in the future, but this is what I'm using now. Let me know if that helps you.